# Putty not connecting via command line - Network error: connection timeout

Tags: command-line, ssh, putty, login

I can usually connect my server via SSH using the Putty.exe interface:

[image]
[image]

But when trying the same via command line:

```
"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\putty.exe" -ssh myuser@mysite.com:2222
```

I get this error:

[image]

What's wrong?

Comment: I don't see "mysite.com" in your settings.

Comment: You probably aren't specifying the alternate port correctly. With `ssh` on a *nix system, it uses a separate flag/argument pair (`-p 2222`) and not a port number appended to the host (what you've done, and what browsers typically do for URLs).  Don't do Windows so I can't tell you for sure, but check the readme/etc for putty... it will list it.